# Add Time Zone picker to Angular Template driven from

Tags: angular, moment-timezone

I want to add Time Zone Picker to my Angular Template driven form.I followed below process.

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

import it to **app.module.ts**

```
import {MomentTimezoneModule} from 'angular-moment-timezone';

imports: [
MomentTimezoneModule  
]
```

Here is my html code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field" appearance="outline">
    <ng-moment-timezone-picker>
  </ng-moment-timezone-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

When I save the changes, it still shows "**Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...**" in terminal.

Comment: Your post isn't exactly clear what your problem is. Are you getting a compilation error or a runtime error? can you post what the error is. Initially it looks like you're at least missing the "formControlName" attribute from the <ng-moment-timezone-picker> (assuming it supports that)

Comment: Your installing something different compared to what your importing. And if I assume angular-moment-timezone is the package.. then that package does not have a <ng-moment-timezone-picker> component (just some pipes for momentjs).